# PHP Laravel can't connect to SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

Error message:

> could not find driver

My dll file: [dll file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0xPw.png)

PHP ini:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_ts_x64.dll

extension=php_sqlsrv_80_ts_x64.dll
```

I'm not sure why, but someone mentioned a local SQL Server with Windows authentication, and despite using it, I'm still facing this issues.

Connect PHP Laravel to SQL Server

Comment: Please don't use images - add the contents directly to the question.

Comment: (1) Make sure you are using the correct dll files for your environment (2) Make sure you have restarted the http service after changing the php.ini

Comment: yes i check phpinfo and still see pdo_sqlsrv here

Comment: Have you read through and followed the instructions in [Loading the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver)? It's also worth having a read through [Microsoft PHP Drivers for SQL Server Support Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix) to understand that (a) each major release of PHP only supports a limited range of driver versions and (b) each driver version only supports a limited range of SQL Server versions.